# Sql Window Analytic function using vega lite

Tags: vega-lite

## The AIM:

Check How many students got the highest mark on the last exam , compare to other exams they have been taken on the SAME SUBJECT.

In sql it is very simple to chive this task.
Bellow are the steps:

## Insert some data (In this case into ElasticSearch):

```
POST /examresult/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{"studentname": "BBB","subject":"Maths","marks": 92,"exam_date":   "22/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{"studentname": "BBB","subject":"Science","marks": 85,"exam_date": "12/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{"studentname": "BBB","subject":"english","marks": 82,"exam_date": "10/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{"studentname": "BBB","subject":"Maths","marks": 80,"exam_date"  : "02/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 5 }}
{"studentname": "BBB","subject":"Science","marks": 65,"exam_date": "28/01/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 6 }}
{"studentname": "BBB","subject":"english","marks": 70,"exam_date": "23/01/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 7 }}
{"studentname": "AAA","subject":"Maths","marks": 50,"exam_date":   "22/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 8 }}
{"studentname": "AAA","subject":"Science","marks": 65,"exam_date": "12/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 9 }}
{"studentname": "AAA","subject":"english","marks": 95,"exam_date": "10/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 10 }}
{"studentname": "AAA","subject":"Maths","marks": 70,"exam_date":   "02/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 11 }}
{"studentname": "AAA","subject":"Science","marks": 72,"exam_date": "28/01/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 12 }}
{"studentname": "AAA","subject":"english","marks": 90,"exam_date": "23/01/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 13 }}
{"studentname": "CCC","subject":"Maths","marks": 90,"exam_date":   "22/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 14 }}
{"studentname": "CCC","subject":"Science","marks": 95,"exam_date": "12/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 15 }}
{"studentname": "CCC","subject":"english","marks": 91,"exam_date": "10/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 16 }}
{"studentname": "CCC","subject":"Maths","marks": 60,"exam_date":   "02/02/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 17 }}
{"studentname": "CCC","subject":"Science","marks": 92,"exam_date": "28/01/2020"}
{ "index": { "_id": 18 }}
{"studentname": "CCC","subject":"english","marks": 89,"exam_date": "23/01/2020"}
```

## Show all the records:

```
select *
from ExamResult
order by studentname,subject,exam_date desc

AAA     Maths   50  22/02/2020  
AAA     Maths   65  12/02/2020  
AAA     Science 95  10/02/2020  
AAA     Science 70  02/02/2020    
AAA     english 72  28/01/2020  
AAA     english 90  23/01/2020  

BBB     Maths   92  22/02/2020  
BBB     Maths   85  12/02/2020  
BBB     Science 82  10/02/2020  
BBB     Science 80  02/02/2020 
BBB     english 65  28/01/2020  
BBB     english 70  23/01/2020  

CCC     Maths   90  22/02/2020  
CCC     Maths   95  12/02/2020  
CCC     Science 91  10/02/2020  
CCC     Science 60  02/02/2020 
CCC     english 92  28/01/2020  
CCC     english 89  23/01/2020
```

## Show Improved details:

```
select *
from
(
SELECT Studentname, 
       Subject, 
       Marks, 
       exam_date,
       (select max(marks) from ExamResult b where a.studentname=b.studentname and a.subject=b.subject)  student_best_score_per_subject
FROM   ExamResult a
where a.exam_date in (select max(b.exam_date)
                        from ExamResult b
                        where b.studentname = a.studentname
                        and   b.subject = a.subject
                        group by b.studentname) 
order by a.studentname,a.exam_date desc
)
where marks >= student_best_score_per_subject

studentname subject     marks   exam_date       student_best_score_per_subject
==============================================================================
AAA         Science     95      10/02/2020      95
BBB         Maths       92      22/02/2020      92
BBB         Science     82      10/02/2020      82
CCC         Science     91      10/02/2020      91
CCC         english     92      28/01/2020      92
```

Now, I need to build a BAR graph on  X axis = subject , on Y axis = Number of students

Which is actually the output of statement bellow:

```
-- Count Improve :
==================
select count(*) IMPROVE , subject
from
(
SELECT Studentname, 
       Subject, 
       Marks, 
       exam_date,
       (select max(marks) from ExamResult b where a.studentname=b.studentname and a.subject=b.subject)  student_best_score_per_subject
FROM   ExamResult a
where a.exam_date = (select max(b.exam_date)
                        from ExamResult b
                        where b.studentname = a.studentname
                        and   b.subject = a.subject
                        group by b.studentname) 
order by a.studentname,a.exam_date desc
)
where marks >= student_best_score_per_subject
group by subject

Improve subject
======= ========
1       english
3       Science
1       Maths
```

Kindly advise how to "translate" this sql statement into vega-lite graph

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide some example data, and an example of what you would like to see? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask a question that is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Could you share the data or mapping that you have and corresponding to that what output do you expect. Without that information, it is difficult for us to proceed any further.

Comment: I have edit the question to be more specific. Kindly Advise

Comment: New input will be appreciated.Thanks